# Closure of the numbers coprime to $n$ under $m$-ary sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of an odd number of odd numbers is odd. This could be generalized as follows:

Given any positive integer $n$, define $X_n$ to be the set of all positive integers $m$ for which the sum of any $m$ numbers coprime to $n$ is itself coprime to $n$.

Then, is it true that $X_n$ is always the following?

- The set of all positive integers if $n=1$
- The set of all odd positive integers if $n=2^k$ for some positive integer $k$
- Just $\{1\}$ by itself otherwise

One thing we could say for sure is that $X_n$ never contains any even numbers for $n>1$. This is because for any positive even integer $m$, $1+(n-1)+1+(n-1)+...+1+(n-1)=nm/2$ (with $m/2$ $1$s and $m/2$ $n-1$s) is divisible by $n$ and hence not coprime to $n$ even though all $m$ numbers are each individually coprime to $n$. Also, the case where $n$ is a power of $2$ is easily verified to give the correct result for both the $n=1$ and $n>1$ subcases.

It remains to show that $1$ is the only element of $X_n$ for any $n$ that is not a power of $2$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the nature of $X_n$. From your description, I think it follows that $m \in X_n \Rightarrow |X_n| \ge m$. OR, does "taking any $m$ numbers" allow for taking one or a few of them multiple times?

Comment: @KeithBackman Repetitions are allowed. What I mean is that if $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$ are $m$ numbers (not necessarily distinct) coprime to $n$, then so is $x_1+x_2+...+x_m$.

Comment: The set $X_{p>3}=\{1,2\}$ where $p$ is prime would seem to meet your criteria, but I lack a proof that more members can't be crammed into the set for any particular $p$

Comment: @KeithBackman No, $2 \notin X_n$ for any $n>1$, regardless of whether $n$ is prime or not, because $1+(n-1)=n$ is not coprime to $n$ even though $1$ and $n-1$ are.

Comment: @KeithBackman Also, another reason that $X_n$ could not possibly be equal to $\{1,2\}$ is that it must be closed under multiplication. Indeed, if $m_1,m_2 \in X_n$, then for any sum of $m_1m_2$ numbers coprime to $n$, one could just divide the sum into $m_1$ groups of $m_2$ numbers each, and the sum of each group is coprime to $n$ since $m_2 \in X_n$, so the sum of those $m_1$ sums (which is equal to the overall sum) is coprime to $n$ since $m_1 \in X_n$, so $m_1m_2 \in X_n$.

Comment: OK. My confusion centers on "all positive integers $m$." If that means all positive integers $m \in\ mathbb N$ that are coprime to $n$, then I see your point. I was thinking all positive integers in $m \in X_n$ that are coprime to $n$, and that is plainly not what you intended.